# Sending variable to PHP through jQuery and back

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a kind of request where registered members see posts of other registered members. They might choose to connect with them before they can be able to comment on the post. What I want is to use jQuery to send the request to PHP which in turn inserts into the database with a status `connection requested`. When the member sees the request he can then choose to accept or reject that request. If he accepts it, the status will change to `you are connected with this member`.

Please I know that there are similar questions like this but not exactly as mine, somebody should please help.

```
'cont_email' is email of member sending request
'email_cont' is email receiving the request
'status' is the status of the connection
'counter' is request increment
```

This is my HTML part:

```
<input name="connect" type="button" value="Connect with&nbsp;<?php     echo"$mem_com[name]";?>" class="intag2" onclick="connt()"/>
```

The PHP part is working ok. My only problem is sending the request through jQuery to PHP and back to jQuery which now displays the status of the connection based on members activity.

Comment: you will need the ajax post/get method to send the variable/s to the external file. this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) will help you

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

Put this content into the file the user's will see (I assume thet the get parameters will be passed to this page when the user lands on them?):

```
<input id="connectButton" name="connect" type="button" value="<?php echo $status;?>" class="intag2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var email_cont = '<?=$_GET[email_cont]?>';
var cont_email = '<?=$_GET[email]?>';

$('#connectButton').click(function() { // add a click event to the button (no need for onclick)
    var counter = 0;
    $.ajax({
       url: 'requests.php?cont_email='+cont_email+'&email_cont='+email_cont+'&counter='+counter,
       success: function( data ) {
           $('#connectButton').val(data); // set the button value to the new status.
           $('#connectButton').unbind('click');   //stop the user clicking the button loads of times.
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then put this in a file called requests.php:

```
<?php

    $email_cont = $_GET['email_cont'];
    $cont_email = $_GET['cont_email'];
    $counter = $_GET['counter'];
    $status = "Connection Sent!";

    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO request VALUES ('','$cont_email','$email_cont','$status', '$counter', NOW())");
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(!result){
        //If it fails to run the SQL return an error.
        echo "Connection Failed!";
    }else{
        //If all goes well, return the status
        echo $status;
    }

?>
```

Not tested, but should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello richi! sorry to bother you, but how do i call the the ajax? not really good at it or rather don't a jack of it but can quickly follow when it is explained.. if i do something like this:

Comment: Keep your 'onclick="connt()"' as it is, and wrap the ajax request in a function called connt(), updated code above.

Comment: function connt(){
    var email_cont = ''; //populate these with the values
    var cont_email = '';
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url_to_your_php_file.php?cont_email='+cont_email+'&email_cont='+email_cont,
      success: function( data ) {
        // 'data' here is the output that your php file give, so in your php file if you 'echo "hello", 'data' will be "hello".
      }
    });
}

Comment: hello richi!!the cont_email and email_cont is post $_GET[cont_email] and $_GET[email_cont] as values to the database. and I have the button value set to $status, but it does change when i click it....please help me

Comment: Can you update your question with the PHP, JS and HTML you are using, so I can see where your code is being run. It's easier for me to debug your code if I can see it :)

Comment: pls follow my link couldn't paste here, i added it as a new question

Comment: Hi Ibe, I have updated my answer after reading your other post.

Comment: wow! richi!, the status did  change when clicked but however the value is not inserted into the database and you can't connect more than one members,also if you refresh the page the status changes back as it was. further,  a members post can appear more than one, once connection is sent to him, all the post bearing his id have to change as well as in the status, I would also want that to happen pls...... thanks

Comment: You need to create a database connection in your php file, and make sure your SQL query is right - I'm sure you can manage that. Also the $status inside the button - where is it being set? You need to get the status from the database before you display the button, so the right value is there. Is there more than one button on a page too? - This is the kinda info you really need to tell people before they can help properly... I can't spend all my time answering more and more questions about the same thing - I'd end up writing your whole application!

Comment: yeah richi you are right!, you can't spend more time talking about same thing!. well mistakes I should have formatted my question properly before throwing it out for solution.however there are more than one button on the page because it displays all the updates post by members.I have also set the status to call from the database,I have also set a connect to the database help me make other button clickable and if member A connect to B, then when C logs in the status for A or B should be the default status ie connect with member A or B.... thank you